# Right to left (RTL) support in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, right-to-left

What would be the best way to implement RTL support in React apps? Is there a way to override default `<p>` and `<span>` tags (components) to add RTL support so that I don't have to rewrite components I already wrote to have RTL support? (for example, to have some global variable `window.RTL`, so when set to true to have all `<p>` and `<span>` tags flip text direction to RTL). I could probably change the build system, or make a babel plugin, that will replace all `React.createElement("p" ...)` with my own implementation of a p tag, but is there a better solution?

Thanks.

Answer (score 13):

A more optimal way is to use CSS / HTML abilities for that:

- `direction` CSS property
- Unicode symbols `&rlm;` / `&lrm;`
- Attach `.rtl` / `.ltr` classes to `body` and use them to change order

In that cases order of your elements in HTML are the same for RTL and LTR. The difference in applied CSS rules.

If you really need the order of elements in React, you can create own component that reverses the list of children if RTL:

```
const Dir = React.createClass({
  render: function() {
    let children = (this.props.direction == 'rtl' && this.props.children && this.props.children.reverse) ? this.props.children.reverse() : null;
    return <div>
      { children }
    </div>;
  }
});

// And use as:
// directionVariable = 'rtl'|'ltr'
<Dir direction={ directionVariable }>
  <a>First</a>
  <a>Second</a>
  <a>Third</a>
</Dir>
```

Comment: I'm looking for a solution that would fix RTL support for existing components, without me having to rewrite them. So I was thinking about extending/patching ReactDOM to enable this functionality. For example, to create ReactDOMWithRTLSupport that could be a drop in replacement for ReactDOM.

Comment: Why not enough CSS rules?

Comment: I don't know if I could solve the problem with just css. If it's possible, great! But I'm thinking that there will probably be more work than that. By replacing those base components I would have more power. Has anyone done this?

Comment: I don't have anything yet, I just have a requirement from my boss to figure out how to add RTL support to a set of existing components, without rewriting them.

Comment: So you don't have experience with RTL?

Comment: I made a markup for RTL websites, and I never touched html tags order and can't imagine some big situations where it needed. All controlled by CSS rules.

Comment: Yes, but here is the issue: there is cssjanus library that does css conversion from LTR to RTL. However, if I use css in js (see https://vimeo.com/116209150) I have to intercept all style props passed to all react components so that I could run them through cssjanus.

Comment: In that case I believe you need a something like a mixin for react... You need to avoid **any** changes of source code or you can put one line on each React component ?

Comment: The issue is that I want to enable RTL on the whole ui component kit that I use, there are too many components to do this manually.

Comment: what about use flex direction of css and only use different rtl.css that replace or override the existing one if the language changed.

Comment: @EranOr yes, it's an option, and plugin like RTLCSS can generate this CSS https://rtlcss.com/

Answer (score 7):

Simple and easy, Just set `dir` attribute of `<html>` in `index.js` as follow:

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import './index.css';
import App from './App';
import * as serviceWorker from './serviceWorker';

ReactDOM.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <App />
  </React.StrictMode>,
  document.getElementById('root')
);

//HERE ->
document.getElementsByTagName('html')[0].setAttribute("dir", "rtl");
//Or you can do it where ever you want, base on user selected language, or something else 
serviceWorker.unregister();
```

UPDATE: If your application is RTL at all, just add `dir="rtl"` in `<html>` tag, but if user can chose different languages that may be RTL or LTR you can do it like above example, and handle other things with CSS...

Just check User chosen language is RTL and `document.getElementsByTagName('html')[0].setAttribute("dir", "rtl");` let CSS handle appearance stuff.

Answer (score 4):

here's your solution:

1. first of all create an array of rtl language locales, like this:

   ```
    const rtlLanguages = ["ar"]
   ```
2. here's how you can update your page direction based on your current language:

   ```
   function setPageDirection(language) {
     const dir = rtlLanguages.includes(language) ? "rtl" : "ltr"
     document.documentElement.dir = dir
   }
   ```
3. now when you set your new language, update the page direction using the function above, like this:

   ```
    setPageDirection("en") // ltr
    setPageDirection("ar") // rtl
   ```

*NOTE:* to automatically update the page direction during first render try storing your current language locale (for example: "en") in localStorage whenever you update your language, and then try using useEffect (or componentDidMount), and use localStorage.getItem to get your language and just call the setPageDirection function and provide the language

Comment: a quick note, if you want to modify your html elements when the direction is right-to-left do this: html[dir="rtl"] .your-class-name {} and viceversa

Answer (score 1):

There is a special HTML tag to use RTL direction:

```css
 bdo {
      unicode-bidi: bidi-override;
    }
```

```html
    <bdo dir="rtl">
      This text will go right-to-left.
    </bdo>
```

https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_bdo.asp

Answer (score 1):

Go to `main.tsx` or `main.js` depending on your project and wrap `<App />` tag with a `<div dir="rtl"></div>` like this

```
 ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById('root') as HTMLElement).render(
  <React.StrictMode>
   <div dir="rtl">
     <App />
   </div>
  </React.StrictMode>
)
```

Answer (score 1):

if you use  react-i18next

```
import React from 'react';
import { useTranslation } from 'react-i18next';
import './App.css';

function App()  {
    const { t, i18n } = useTranslation();
    document.body.dir = i18n.dir();
    return (
      <div className="App">
        {t('welcome')}
      </div>
    );
}

export default App;
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm using react-i18next to change the position from left to right when the Arabic language is chosen. I did the flowing, and it worked for me.

first i went to to the index.html and wrote this inside of body tag:

```
<body dir="ltr">
```

which will allow the page to left to write when the direction is chosen.
lastly i add this line in my App.js which is my main code:

```
document.body.dir = i18n.dir(); //this will change the direction of the dir in the index.html.
```