# ReactJs with rtl and ltr

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, right-to-left

I am developing  a web app on ReactJS bilingual.
I am facing an issue with language changing between Arabic and English and vice versa. I have tried to use dir Rtl and dir Ltr
I need to change the body with picture, logo and header .
I here tried to use plugin, but still not solved

```
  changeLtr=()=> {
    
        }

    changeRtl=()=> {
    
        }
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34899513/right-to-left-rtl-support-in-react

Answer (score 0):

You can use the jss-rtl plugin: https://github.com/alitaheri/jss-rtl

This plugin enables right-to-left support by flipping every rule on the x-axis.